# ImDisk API issue in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, dll, class-library, ramdisk

I have been working on implementing [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk) into my C# project, where I can create RAMDisk on the fly. Unfortunately due to absolutely no examples, I am at a bit lost as to how to resolve this issue.

I am receiving the error **Unable to find an entry point named '_ImDiskFindFreeDriveLetter@0' in DLL 'imdisk.cpl'.** which, after Google searches, is apparently from not initiating an object. However, ImDiskAPI has no constructors, and cannot be initiated in that manner, so I am at a bit of a stand-still. When I attempt to initialize an instance, I get **The type 'LTR.IO.ImDisk.ImDiskAPI' has no constructors defined**

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to get this going?

Comment: FYI there is no such thing as C#.NET. The language is named "C#".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that there is a DLL missing. 
You need to place the ImDisk.cpl file into your application's directory.
The managed wrapper library needs the ImDisk.cpl file to function properly.

Hope, this helps.

Comment: The developer just replied to me, and apparently I found a bug that had not been noticed before. As soon as I switched over to X86 (was building as X64) it worked fine. Thank you for the help.